# Making REST calls in parallel in Apache Camel

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

I am using Apache Camel Java DSL in a Spring Boot project. In the Camel route, I am calling two rest services sequentially, combining their outputs and sending to another application from the Camel route. Now we are trying to call the REST services in parallel. We were able to call the REST services in parallel by implementing the following steps:

1. In the route, first storing the two URLs of the two REST services in a list within an exchange.
2. Applying Splitter EIP and parallelProcessing() on that EIP to call two differrent Camel routes in parallel which calls the REST service.
3. Unmarshalling the response of the services from JSON to POJO

The problem is if I use an aggregationStrategy to aggregate the responses, how canI handlethe scenarion when the two REST services will return two different objects after unmarshalling the response? Also please suggest any better approach of calling the REST services in parallel and consolidating their responses.

Comment: You could use multicast instead of splitter, but without knowing more about the context and expectations of the REST services it's very hard to give any advice on handling the returned responses.

Comment: I am calling two rest services A and B which returns two different JSONs (say ResponseA and ResponseB). Now in the camel route, I will have to capture the two responses, prepare another JSON by taking some attributes from ResponseA and some attributes from ResponseB (say ResponseC), the use the consolidated JSON in exchange for further processing. I am not able to prepare ResponseC from ResponseA and ResponseB

Comment: Ok, so I think you are on the right track with aggregation strategy upon receiving the responses.

Comment: Yes, my question is how can I handle the multiple objects received from response of different API calls? Since when I am calling them in parallel, I will not be able to say which response will come first and which later i.e. which message is within old Exchange and which one is within new Exchange?

Comment: Using multicast with aggeregation strategy is a better approach than using splitter, thanks for the sugesstion.